# 18.04 - Wifi Hotspot does not come up after reboot

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, network-manager, hot-spot

I had a working WiFi Hotspot config, but after reboot it doesn't come up.
Syslog tells me : https://pastebin.com/Te4ik2Yq

looks like the "Problem" is here:

```
Jul 23 08:51:37 testmachine01 NetworkManager[6346]: <info>  [1532335897.7097] dnsmasq-manager: starting dnsmasq...
Jul 23 08:51:37 testmachine01 NetworkManager[6346]: <info>  [1532335897.7121] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 23 08:51:37 testmachine01 NetworkManager[6346]: dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 172.30.108.1: Address already in use
Jul 23 08:51:37 testmachine01 dnsmasq[7090]: failed to create listening socket for 172.30.108.1: Address already in use
Jul 23 08:51:37 testmachine01 dnsmasq[7090]: FAILED to start up
Jul 23 08:51:37 testmachine01 NetworkManager[6346]: <warn>  [1532335897.7131] dnsmasq-manager: dnsmasq exited with error: Network access problem (address in use, permissions) (2)
Jul 23 08:51:37 testmachine01 NetworkManager[6346]: <info>  [1532335897.7131] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-check -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 23 08:51:37 testmachine01 NetworkManager[6346]: <warn>  [1532335897.7137] device (wlp1s0): Activation: failed for connection 'HotSpot'
Jul 23 08:51:37 testmachine01 NetworkManager[6346]: <info>  [1532335897.7144] device (wlp1s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

I don't have specifically dnsmasq installed, "just" using NetworkManager

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: After some research it seems that NM is using dnsmasq-base which is hard coded. I don't have the full dnsmaq installed. BUT I do have bind9 installed as I need to work with views to restrict certain queries from the network connected to the wifi ap. Looks like this is the main problem here. How can I assign a static IP to the wifi-AP, allow dhcp for the clients but NOT have dnsmasq trying to bind to port 53 as this is already done by bind9?

Comment: you can add manually IP address at your Hotspot/devices connected on your hotspot; you won't have to care about the dhcp server with something like that, and to assign the IP address, use `ifconfig <network card> <IP address>` (for example, `ifconfig wlp5s0 192.168.5.2`)

Comment: tried adding dns=none in the main section of NetworkManager.conf but still the same issue: Bind9 binds to the Interface, then dnsmasq is trying to do the same and failed which brings down the complete HotSpot.

Comment: @damadam but I need some sort of DHCP to assign IP addresses to the clients. Manually assigning an IP doesn't solve the problem itself, as the IP itself does get assigned properly

Comment: Maybe I should purge bind9 and install full dnsmasq. But can I work with "views" in dnsmasq just like in bind?

Answer (score 0):

A Wifi hotspot use the same device than you use it to go on internet with this computer; this network card have 2 mode :

- receiver mode (default); this mode is compulsory if you want to download updates
- transmitter mode (case of the hotspot)

I pretty sure you can't start your hotspot because Ubuntu is downloading updates or something like that, so the network card is already used. The fact you said this issue occured after a reboot increased the chance of automatic updates download.

Solution : You just have to wait a little so this operation can finish, and then, you will be able to start your Wifi hotspot

Comment: Nope, that's not the case. I have a default ethernet connection and using the wifi ONLY as hotpot.